# Trouble connecting outlets to information

Tags: iphone, view, uiview, porting

I am porting an application from iPad to iPhone, making it universal. I have a tableView with a list objects and then a view with information on each object. On the iPad everything works fine, and I have made a new tableview for iPhone which also works.

What does not work is that the information on the objects doesn´t display in the view on the iPhone. I have some images, labels and textviews connected to some outlets. These are "populated" by AppDelegate. I can connect the outlets, but they don´t display the information. No errors in console appear.

Any one have any suggestions?

EDIT: removed "med" (typo, norwegian kicked in).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding NSLogs to ensure the outlets are non-null at the time you're populating them? If you trying to populate outlets before the view itself is loaded, the outlets are nil at that time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I haven´t. I am pretty new to xcode, so don´t know about NSLog. Another thing about my App is that the iPad version uses Split View and therefore I load the Outlets in the Refresh-method, but the iPhone is a new view, so I am trying to load them in ViewDidLoad, but doesn´t work. I have added a textview programmatically in the ViewDidLoad and this appears, but no content (i added background color etc, so I can see it). But that textview is also suppose to load from AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set the delegate and/or data source of the table view. Either do this programmatically or link it up from IB.